# Bad File descriptor error due to socket reconnection

Tags: c, sockets

Actually I am trying to identify a problem, can close(sockFD) for a socket more than once will generate exception in file reading within the same process.
Here is the stuff that is creating problem :
I have two threads :

- one thread is responsible to create a connection with server. it will retry to make connection with server in a sleep of 10 secs if not connected.
- second thread reads 2 files and process both. and also waits for connection to be established by other thread first time.

What I have done, First thread is connected to server successfully and then it goes down
After that, main thread processes first file correctly but fails to read second file each time.
If connection made by other thread with server is persistent, both files are processed successfully.

I want to know what could be the reason behind this.
Is a call to close(sockFD) is affecting the file descriptor of second file??

Comment: Calling close on the same file descriptor is bad not only because you're told not to do it.  It's bad because the same file descriptor is entirely likely to have been reused, and now you're closing something else.